# Get state from renderScene function (Navigator) in React Native

Tags: react-native, ecmascript-6, reactjs

When I try to get a state of an element from renderScene function (Navigator), I have an error. It seems I couldn't get any state from that function.

For instance:

```
constructor(props) {

  super(props);

  this.state = {
    test: 'test ok'
  };

}

renderScene(route, navigator) {

  console.log('test ok'); // test ok

  console.log(this.state.test); // Cannot read property 'test' of undefined

  ...

}

render() {

  return (
    <Navigator
      ...
      renderScene={this.renderScene}
      ...
    />
  )

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use

```
renderScene={this.renderScene.bind(this)}
```

Comment: Thanks! I finally understand the need of this! =)